# Is it possible to specify a time interval (from, to) in ACF with date picker, or other custom field?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, date, datepicker

I am working on an online magazine in WordPress PHP (with Advanced Custom Fields plugin). I specify the date of the article's publication with 'date picker' field. Even though for articles representing events, a time interval should be defined, in the form of 'from-to'. As I noticed, there is no option for this in date picker, or other fields. Or does such a field exist in ACF? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no native "Time Interval" field type in ACF, but you could:

- Use a third-party custom field like the "[Date Range Picker](https://www.acf-extended.com/features/fields/date-range-picker)" provided by [ACF Extended](https://www.acf-extended.com/) (it's a commercial plugin that adds features to ACF).
- Use 2 distinct native Date Picker fields for "from" and "to", possibly inserted inside a Group. You may take advantage of some existing snippets to display the value ([example](https://gist.github.com/brianjhanson/17e33b1d008fd69e3ea5)).